# React native - Iterating using MAP

Tags: react-native

Not sure what's wrong, but I've this json...

```
CONTENT = {
"pages": {
    "p1": {
        "backgroundImage": require("../assets/pageBkgs/p1.png"),
        "backgroundColor": "#FF0000",
        "elements": [
            {
                "jumpTo": {
                    "left": 500,
                    "top": 500,
                    "width": 100,
                    "height": 100,
                    "target": "p3"
                },
                "video" : {
                    "left": 200,
                    "top": 200,
                    "width": 100,
                    "height": 100,
                    "file": require("../assets/videos/limenice.mp4")
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

and this should be iterate an return accordly:

```
<View style={styles.pageContainer}>
                {
                    CONTENT.pages[pageKey].elements.map(element => {
                        const type = Object.keys(element).toString()
                        alert(Object.keys(element).toString())
                        switch (type) {
                            case "jumpTo":
                                return JumpTo(Object.values(element)[0], this.executeJumpTo.bind(this), CONTENT.designTime)
                                break
                            case "video":
                                return VideoPlayer(Object.values(element)[0], CONTENT.designTime)
                                break
                            default:
                                return null
                        }
                    })
                }
            </View>)
```

The alert show: "jumpTo,video"

I am trying to archive something like...

```
for(let i=0; i < CONTENT.pages[pageKey].elements.length;i++) {
   switch (Object.keys(CONTENT.pages[pageKey].elements[i]).toString()) {
                        case "jumpTo":
                            return JumpTo(Object.values(element)[0], this.executeJumpTo.bind(this), CONTENT.designTime)
                            break
                        case "video":
                            return VideoPlayer(Object.values(element)[0], CONTENT.designTime)
                            break
                        default:
                            return null
                    }
}
```

where I am expecting a result of 2 alerts: jumpTo and video (instead both separated by comma)

Any clue ? I think it's a basic functional programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

To get two subsequent alerts:

```
Object.keys(CONTENT.pages[pageKey].elements).each(type => alert(type));
```

To return two subsequent components `[JumpTo, VideoPlayer]`:

```
{ Object.keys(CONTENT.pages[pageKey].elements).map(type => switch(type) {
     /* your case statements */
}); }
```